# NavigationDrawer with tabs

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-tabs

I want to implement a [NavigationDrawer](https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html) in combination with tabs, like in the PlayStore app:

[image]

So the basic idea is to have a [android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout.html) as the [AppCompatActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html)'s root element, and that contains a [android.support.design.widget.NavigationView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html) and the main content (switched by a FrgmentTransaction):

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout >

    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/main_content"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/main_navigation"
        app:menu="@menu/main_navigation" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The tabs are implemented like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/main_tabbed_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

But I don't know how to fuse this together:

- Is my approach of using fragments in the `<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/main_content"/>` right, or should I launch a new Activity on each NavigationView click?
- I have tabbed and non-tabbed fragments, and how do I bind all their custom Toolbars to the root DrawerLayout for displaying the 'sandwich icon'? (using a [ActionBarDrawerToggle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html)?)
- Will I run into performance-issues with this?

Please comment if I need to clarify something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement each page in the navigation view as a separate `Fragment`. This way, you shouldn't have to include a `Toolbar` in any of them because the root `Activty's` `Toolbar` will always be shown.

As far as performance is concerned, I've used similar patterns and been fine, and I think the Android platform will handle it as long as you do everything else responsibly.

Here's an example of how you could organize this:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.myapplication.ui.activity.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <include layout="@layout/widget_toolbar" />

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/coordinator_layout" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

A `RelativeLayout` holds `fragment_container` below the `Toolbar`, so the same `Toolbar` will be displayed regardless of which `Fragment` is put into `fragment_container` because it belongs to the `Activity`.

Comment: But how can I add tabs below the toolbar if it is not declared in the fragment?

Comment: Since the toolbar is part of the activity and not the fragment conatiner, it will not be affected by fragment transactions. I updated my answer with an example implementation.

Comment: This is not what I looked for, because the `TabLayout` won't clip to the `Toolbar`, since they are not part of the same `AppBarLayout`.

Comment: Did you try moving the `FrameLayout` inside the `AppBarLayout` below the `Toolbar`? That might be what you're looking for